# How to convert window object to string in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I've an AppleScript that retrieves window id of an app.
Example following script retrieves the window id of Brave Browser.

```
set urls to {"https://google.com"}
tell application "Brave Browser"
    set myNewWindow to make new window
    repeat with theURL in urls
        tell myNewWindow to open location theURL
    end repeat
    delay 0.3
    log myNewWindow
    return class of myNewWindow //comment - returns "window" as a class
end tell
```

My goal is it possible to convert the window id to a string and vice-versa.

**Why conversion?**

- I want to save window id in UserDefaults on macOS.

Note: This AppleScript is used in macOS app.

Comment: Just coerce the result to text: `class of myNewWindow as text` but this is the  **name** of the class, not an id

Comment: I tried the same on the actual id of the window, it throws an error "Can't make window id 15" of application into type text.

Comment: Can't you store the window id as number? Why do you want to save the window id in `UserDefaults`, when are you going to use it? Can you give an example of the string you want?

Comment: yes we could store it as a number too, I was more like into just store the output of everthing the property returns.  Anyways, it turns out converting the window object to string/number doesn't work out at all. My end usecase is "tell application "Brave Browser" to close "window id 527"(this string should be a window object)

Comment: Regarding "where are you going to use it"..I want to store it so that when user wants to close the window they can close the specific window using the id whenever they want.

Comment: `tell application "Brave Browser" to close "window id 527"` doesn't work, Brave Browser can't close a string. Do you want to store the window id in Swift? Do you want to quit the app and get the window id from UserDefaults later?

Comment: @Willeke absolutely correct that exactly I want to do. Incase, if it is not possible in Swift I am fine with if we can store somewhere using "defaults write"

Comment: A _window id_ is generated dynamically and most likely wouldn’t be the same between application runs - are you talking about a _name_ or an _object specifier_?

Comment: For my usecase, application runs is irrelevant as I use that window id only for that specific run. @red_menace

Comment: How are Swift and AppleScript connected? How is the AppleScript created and executed? Is it one AppleScript? Add a bit more context to the question please.

Comment: I have two buttons in macOS app - Open Browser window and Close Browser window. Each button has its own applescript to execute it and the common thing between those applescript should be the window id. I need to track the window id either in applescript or swift but my end goal is what ever the browser window was opened, I should be able to close that specific window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, it's hard for me to understand why the ID should be kept in defaults. Because **theID** variable will already store this value throughout the script. And at any time you can close the window using a variable in a later part of the script. I can only assume one thing: you want to open a window locally and then close it from other script executed on a remote machine.

And getting the window ID in Brave Browser as text is easy:

```
set urls to {"https://google.com"}
tell application "Brave Browser"
    set myNewWindow to make new window
    repeat with theURL in urls
        open location theURL
    end repeat
    delay 0.3
    set theID to (id of myNewWindow) as text --> the ID of window in  text form
end tell

-- write theID value to defaults here
```

Closing the window from other script:

```
-- first, read theID from defaults here

tell application "Brave Browser"
    close window id (theID as integer)
end tell
```